# Add a visual indicator to posts having pending suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

When the "Suggested Edits" system was first introduced, it was the newest shiny thing.  Edits were approved so quickly that by the time you clicked on the "Edits Pending" number at the top of the page, often the edits would already be approved and the queue would already be clear.

However, lately approval of suggested edits has lagged, and the queue sometimes fills up with suggested edits.  Timely approval of suggested edits is especially important for new questions, which have a very short shelf life on Stack Overflow, and can potentially benefit the most from a speedy edit.

Can we add a visual indicator to the page to indicate that a suggested edit is pending, and entice qualified approvers to click on it?  I know we already have a number in parentheses next to the edit link, but that's very subtle, and unless someone is considering editing the post themselves, they'll never look at that.

It doesn't have to be really blatant.  Changing the style of the edit link to bold white text on a burnt orange background (similar to the Edits Pending number) would probably suffice.

Comment: Does a `<blink>` sound good?

Comment: Normally I'd say no to blinking anything, but in this case, it might actually be ideal. `<serious />`

Comment: Uh, I...was not being serious. (:

Comment: @RobertHarvey Regrettably, `<blink>` isn't supported by WebKit so this wouldn't be a viable solution. :'(

Comment: "Review this suggested edit to see [beautiful women|gorgeous men]! * Requires Google"

Comment: I bet if you let 2k users see the queue too, it would empty much quicker.  Maybe as a tab in the review screen?

Comment: At the moment, there's 70 pending edits in the queue.  I cleared out 45 myself yesterday.